# How is the doc for a property accessed?

Tags: python

I have a property with a docstring, but I can't seem to access that using `help()`.

I tried the following two ways of accessing it:

```
class Mini(object):
    @property
    def t(self):
        """ ahhhh """
        return 0

x = Mini()
help(x.t)

class MiniNew(object):
    t = property(doc='This is a doc')

y = MiniNew()
help(y.t)
```

The first help returned `Help on int object: blahblahblah` and the later one returned `AttributeError: unreadable attribute`.

What is the right way to access the doc of a property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to access the property from the class.  When accessed from an instance, it acts like the returned value, which is not the thing you documented.

```
class Example(object):
    @property
    def value(self):
        """help text"""
        return 1

help(Example.value)
```

This will print:

```
Help on property:

    help text
```